# Why does Outlook cut off part of my hyperlink?

Tags: microsoft-outlook

Our web-site generates an e-mail containing a hyperlink something along the lines of:

```
http://www.website.com/page.asp?GUID='{LisTofRandomLetterS}'
```

When I receive the e-mail to my web-mail account it works perfectly, opening a new tab and the correct page. The problem is when it is received by Microsoft Outlook, it appears as:

```
http://www.website.com/page.asp?GUID='{LisTofRandomLetterS}
```

It opens a new tab but the tab remains blank since the argument is missing the final `'`.

I would hope that this has a simple resolution, just that I cannot find it - any help available?

Comment: Can you confirm the web-mail account IS the same account as that on Outlook please? I normally would recommend against using quote marks in the query string as well (just my opinion).

Comment: No, it's not the same account Dave. In testing the page, i generate the e-mails to my 'home' account as well as my work's. It is my works address which uses Outlook.

Comment: Can you actually view the HTML of the email before it sends (maybe try to send 1 email as plain text to see the HTML - this will confirm that the body is correct)

Answer (score 0):

My guess is it is a formatting issue.

So your link may be

```
<a href='http://www.website.com/page.asp?GUID='{123-456-789}'>link</a>
```

As you can see from the example above, there is one too few quote marks - the render takes the final ' as the closing of the a tag in Outlook, but not in your web client.

Comment: Thanks for your help Dave, it does look like that could be the culprit. The e-mail is generated by a form so i will have to look into the form code.

Comment: asp = vbscript - I spent 5 years doing it, if you want help paste your code.